# GORM - uniqueIndex with soft delete

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I'm using Gorm's unique index to enforce a certain ordering of elements

```
type Element struct {
  gorm.Model
  ID         int            `gorm:"primary_key"`
  Index      int            `gorm:"uniqueIndex:unique_order"`
  ParentID   int            `gorm:"uniqueIndex:unique_order"`
}
```

The problem I'm running into is when I create and delete multiple elements I start to get an error like

```
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "unique_order" (SQLSTATE 23505)
```

This is happening because Gorm soft deletes elements by setting deleted_at, but the rows still exist in the database and the unique index is still enforced.

I know I can get around this using a partial index in Postgres SQL, but I'm wondering if there's a way I can handle this with Gorm?